# xcrysden not opening

Tags: software-installation, software-sources, error-handling

i just installed xcrysden in my Ubuntu which i am using on virtual machine, but whenevr i tried to open it , iam getting an error like--

```
***********Pc:~$ xcrysden

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|*****************************************************************|
|*                                                               *|
|*  XCrySDen -- (X-Window) CRYstalline Structures and DENsities  *|
|*               =         ===         =              ===        *|
|*---------------------------------------------------------------*|
|*                                                               *|
|*    Anton Kokalj (tone.kokalj@ijs.si)                          *|
|*    Jozef Stefan Institute, Ljubljana, Slovenia                *|
|*                                                               *|
|*    Copyright (c) 1996--2019 by Anton Kokalj                   *|
|*                                                               *|
|*****************************************************************|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+

  Version: 1.6.2

  Please report bugs to: tone.kokalj@ijs.si


  TERMS OF USE:
  -------------
  XCRYSDEN is released under the GNU General Public License.

  Whenever graphics generated by XCRYSDEN are used in scientific
  publications, it shall be greatly appreciated to include an explicit
  reference. The preferred form is the following:

  [ref] A. Kokalj, J. Mol. Graph. Model., Vol. 17, pp. 176-179, 1999.
        Code available from http://www.xcrysden.org/.

XCRYSDEN_TOPDIR=/usr/share/xcrysden
XCRYSDEN_SCRATCH=/tmp

Running on platform : unix
   Operating system : Linux
Package ImageMagick's convert: /usr/bin/convert
Package ImageMagick's import: /usr/bin/import
Package Ppmtompeg: /usr/bin/ppmtompeg
Package Xwd: /usr/bin/xwd
Executing: /usr/lib/xcrysden/ftnunit
Error in startup script:
Couldn't configure togl widget
    while executing
"togl .mesa  -width          400  -height         400  -ident          .mesa  -rgba           $toglOpt(rgba)           -redsize        $toglOpt(redsize..."
    (procedure "PlaceGlobWin" line 107)
    invoked from within
"PlaceGlobWin 0 [expr round(670 * $fac1)] [expr round(670 * $fac1)]"
    (procedure "ViewMol" line 25)
    invoked from within
"ViewMol ."
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $argv] > 2 } {
    parseComLinArg [lrange $argv 2 end]
} else {
    ViewMol .
}"
    (file "/usr/share/xcrysden/Tcl/xcInit.tcl" line 633)


********LinxPc:~$
```

can anyone helpme with this error.

thank you,
krk.

Comment: What **version** of Ubuntu are you using? In particular, are you trying to run the software in a Wayland session? See for example [running xcrysden in wayland](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702305/running-xcrysden-in-wayland)

Comment: I installed the latest version of Ubuntu 22.04 and i installed x11 but didn't installed wayland in my ubuntu

Comment: The "`Couldn't configure togl widget`" message implies that you're missing the "togl widget", Did you install all the dependencies for it? Check http://www.xcrysden.org/ for installation instructions.

Comment: now i freshly installed UBUNTU now and it is working on Wayland but same error and i installed togl